# How do I rollback an Oracle Transaction?

Tags: oracle, transactions

I’m trying to test an Oracle Transaction.

I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    data varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES(1,'apple');
INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES(2,'banana');
INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES(3,'cherry');
INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES(4,'date');
```

I wanted to see whether I could do a trial `DELETE` with this:

```sql
--  Trial DELETE
    SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
    DELETE FROM test;
    SELECT * FROM test;
    ROLLBACK;

--  Original Data
    SELECT * FROM test;
```

Well, the code works, but the `test` table is now empty. It doesn’t appear to have benefited from the `ROLLBACK` statement.

Is this the right way to do this?

I have a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/xxcVjl9A but I can’t get the transaction part to run.

Answer (score 2):

You need to commit after doing your inserts. Then you can test your delete and rollback.  Currently your rollback is rolling back the inserts as well as the delete.

Comment: And it's worth to explicitly set autocommit option to `off`, which may be enabled by default (for example, as for JDBC connections).